# Getting Facebook Page mobile uploads gallery feed

Tags: facebook

I am attempting to get the feed to use on a website from a facebook page gallery "Timeline Photos - id: 340294549336" or "Mobile Uploads - id: 10150324255959337".

This used to be working, and decoded with json:
https://graph.facebook.com/10150324255959337/photos
also tried
https://graph.facebook.com/10150324255959337?fields=photos

Do these galleries now require an app and token just to get the feed? I have checked page settings for age, country, profanity... everything has no restrictions.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is related to the graph url would required token

Comment: Thanks, I will have to look more into using tokens to display these galleries.